# Rspec tests output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I run rspect test (I'm using rspec 2 btw).

So that the console only outputs the dots instead of full test log, I've seen it before where green dots are passed tests and the red ones are the failed ones, along with the test outputs the red ones only at the end of test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `.rspec` file from (in you main folder)

```
--format documentation
```

to

```
--format progress
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-f` option to enable documentation format:

```
rspec -f d spec/
```

and `-b` option to enable full backtrace:

```
rspec -b spec/
```